# Android How to create a json from array and send to php server

Tags: php, android, json, arraylist

I am working on an application that generates list of install applications and create a json and send the json to my php server. At php server the I have to get all data and process it acordingly.

This is the code that generates list of installed applications:

```
List<PackageInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    ArrayList<String[]> aux = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++)
    {
        if (apps.get(i).versionCode != 0 && ((apps.get(i).applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 1))
        {
            String[] temp = new String[2];

            String name = apps.get(i).packageName;
            String versionName = apps.get(i).versionName;
            temp[0] = name;
            temp[1] = versionName;
            aux.add(temp);
        }
    }
```

This is the code to send it in json form to php server:

```
try
        {
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("Applications", aux);
            URL url = new URL(IPClass.SERVERPath + "update.php");

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            //OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(os);

            writer.write(String.valueOf(aux));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();


            InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            Log.d("doInBackground(Resp)", result.toString());

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("Ex", ex.toString());
        }
```

The problem is that the json is not getting generated properly and second how can i get it on php server!

Any help please!
Thanks

Comment: Where you are creating json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work fine.

```
JSONArray installedList = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++)
{
    if (apps.get(i).versionCode != 0 && ((apps.get(i).applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 1))
    {
        String name = apps.get(i).packageName;
        String versionName = apps.get(i).versionName;
        JSONObject installedPackage = new JSONObject();
        installedPackage.put("name", name);
        installedPackage.put("versionName", versionName);
        installedList.put(installedPackage);
    }
}
String dataToSend = installedList.toString();
```

Adding this line won't magically turn your array to JSON format.

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

You have to create JSONArray or JSONObject. I recommend you create JSONArray with JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.putString("key", "value");
```

And to make it String:

```
json.toString();
```